# Large GB File upload to webserver

Tags: python, django, file-upload, fastapi, large-file-upload

I have a requirement, where I want to create a **web app**(Either in **Django** or **Fast API** along with **js** in frontend), In which the user can upload large files (groups of files each file will be 3-4 GB), The collective size of these files may range **30-50 GB**. How to approach this requirement. Can anyone help me navigate this requirement?

Comment: What's your actual problem? Handling uploads? Handling large uploads in django or FastAPI? How to store the data after receiving the uploaded file? Handling resumes from the client?